# ¿Cómo contar las filas de una tabla con un criterio?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Tengo un proyecto php conectado a una base de datos en MYSQL que tiene el siguiente código que cuenta las filas de una tabla con id = "table" y muestra el resultado en un input con id = "TotalRegistros"

```
 <script>   
        function Registros(){
        var TotalRegistros= document.getElementById("table").rows.length;
        document.getElementById("TotalRegistros").value = TotalRegistros;
        }
    </script>
```

La tabla tiene el campo 'ESTADO' que puede tener datos como Registrado, Sin Registrar, Por Registrar

¿Cómo puedo hacer para contar las filas de esa tabla utilizando algún criterio?

Registrado: 2
Sin Registrar: 0
Por Registrar: 1

Muchas gracias.

Comment:  hola, no puedes traer un objeto por una query con los atributos listos?

Comment: Por que no haces la cuenta por la query de sql y luego solo utilizas ese valor?. No se cual es la estructura de tu/s tabla/s pero pongo un ejemplo de un libro:
select count(*) from libros where autor like '%Borges%';. Podrías depositar eso en una variable y hacer con ella lo que desees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es mas facil obtener el valor directamente desde PHP, pero si no puedes acceder a editar esa parte del codigo, tambien lo puedes hacer con JavaScript

No compartes mas detalles de tu tabla asi que hago aqui una de ejemplo:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  // Cuenta todas las filas
  let reg = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;
  
  // Agrega resultado a un elemento de HTML, resto uno porque el resultado incluye el header de la tabla
  let results = document.getElementById("total");
  results.innerText = (reg - 1);
  
  // Prepara los elementos que recibiran los resultados
  let elem1 = document.getElementById("result-1");
  let elem2 = document.getElementById("result-2");
  let elem3 = document.getElementById("result-3");
  
  // Obten todas las columnas y conviertelas a un arreglo
  let source = document.querySelectorAll("td");
  let arr = Array.from(source);
  
  // Arreglo con los valores a buscar
  let lookup = [
    "Registrado",
    "Sin Registrar",
    "Por Registrar",
  ];
  
  // Aplicando el metodo filter para devolver los resultados
  let res1 = arr.filter(item => item.innerText == lookup[0]);
  let res2 = arr.filter(item => item.innerText == lookup[1]);
  let res3 = arr.filter(item => item.innerText == lookup[2]);
  
  // Contando el numero de resultado por cada filtro e imprimiendolos en pantalla
  elem1.innerText = res1.length;
  elem2.innerText = res2.length;
  elem3.innerText = res3.length;
  
}, false);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <th>
      Item
    </th>
    <th>
      Archivo
    </th>
    <th>
      Estado
    </th>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        1
      </td>
      <td>
        File 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Registrado
      </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>
        2
      </td>
      <td>
        File 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Registrado
      </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>
        3
      </td>
      <td>
        File 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Sin Registrar
      </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>
        4
      </td>
      <td>
        File 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Por Registrar
      </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>
        5
      </td>
      <td>
        File 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Registrado
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<p>
  <span>Total Registros: </span><span id="total"></span><br />
  <span>Registrados: </span><span id="result-1"></span><br />
  <span>Sin Registrar: </span><span id="result-2"></span><br />
  <span>Por Registrar: </span><span id="result-3"></span><br />
</p>
```

Suerte con el codigo

Comment: Funciona, MUCHAS GRACIAS!

Comment: Una pregunta, que puedo añadir para que cuente filas con dos criterios al mismo tiempo...   por ejemplo si en la tabla hay tres registros de FILE 1, dos de esos en el estado de REGISTRADO y uno en el estado de SIN REGISTRAR, y se muestre el resultado 2. Muchas gracias.

Comment: El metodo filter devuelve un objeto del tipo arreglo, entonces primero aplicas filter al tipo de archivo que te devolvera un arreglo filtrado, y luego a este arreglo, aplicar una vez mas un filter usando el otro valor para discrminar los resultados